# javascript TypeError: 'undefined' when evaluating a 2d array

Tags: javascript

this is my code :

```
var y = new Array(); // it have 500 entries.
var z = [[]];
    var counter =0;
    for(var i =0; i<49;i++){
        for(var j=0; j<9;j++){
            z[i][j] = y[counter];
            counter +=1;
        }
    }
    console.log(z);
```

and I am getting this error : `TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'z[i][j] = y[counter]')`

what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: You are trying to access `z[0][1]` which doesn't exist. `var z = [[]];` creates an array with a **single** element (another array). JavaScript doesn't have multidimensional arrays, you have to create every element of an array explicitly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to initialize each row of the two-dimensional array.  Your declaration:

```
var z = [[]];
```

only creates row 0.

So:

```
for(var i =0; i<49;i++){
    z[i] = []; // <===== initialize the row
    for(var j=0; j<9;j++){
        z[i][j] = y[counter];
        counter +=1;
    }
}
```